# Scaling Normal Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, normal-families

Why is it that $N(0, ct) = \sqrt c N(0,t)$? What does it mean when we take a constant out of a distribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that $X \sim N(0,t)$, i.e. $X$ is a random variable with normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $t$, if and only if $\sqrt{c} X \sim N(0,ct)$.  Multiplication by $\sqrt{c}$ always multiplies the variance of a random variable by $c$ and the mean by $\sqrt{c}$.  The normal distributions are rather special in that multiplication by a constant preserves the fact of being normal; this can be seen from considering the density.